# How to log stack trace?

Tags: asp.net, iis

How can I increase log level in order to log stack traces, anytime a 500 error happens?

Is it something to do in the my code or in the IIS' site configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in code behind by catching the `Exception` and accessing the `StackTrace` property. It would look something like this:

```
     try
        {
           //your code 
        }
     catch( Exception ex )
        {

            Console.WriteLine( 
                "\nStackTrace ---\n{0}", ex.StackTrace );
        }
```

This write the Stack trace to the console window.

In order to write the message to a log text file you could do something like this

```
public static void LogException(Exception exc, string source)
{

    // Get the absolute path to the log file

    string logFile = "App_Data/ErrorLog.txt";
    logFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logFile);

    // Open the log file for append and write the log
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true);
    sw.WriteLine("********** {0} **********", DateTime.Now);
    sw.Write("Exception Type: ");
    sw.WriteLine(exc.GetType().ToString());
    sw.WriteLine("Exception: " + exc.Message);
    sw.WriteLine("Source: " + source);
    sw.WriteLine("Stack Trace: ");
    if (exc.StackTrace != null)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

[Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

So putting the two together the following will do what you want:

```
     try
        {
           //your code 
        }
     catch( Exception ex )
        {

            string logFile = "App_Data/ErrorLog.txt";
    logFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logFile);

    // Open the log file for append and write the log
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true);
    sw.WriteLine("********** {0} **********", DateTime.Now);
    sw.Write("Exception Type: ");
    sw.WriteLine(exc.GetType().ToString());
    sw.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
    sw.WriteLine("Source: " + source);
    sw.WriteLine("Stack Trace: ");
    if (exc.StackTrace != null)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
    sw.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS already logs this by default -- look at the event log on the IIS server.

You can capture this and send it wherever you'd like using [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) though you might also want to work at better exception handlers like ELMAH while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is good support for logging errors using

[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729(v=pandp.60).aspx)